# Installing redmine_contacts plugin for bitnami_redmine

Tags: plugins, redmine, sprockets

I am trying to install redmine_contacts plugin for my redmine 2.2.3.0 (which is installed using BITNami installer), as in readme.rdoc:

- Copy redmine_contacts plugin to {RAILS_APP}/plugins on your redmine path
- Run bundle install --without development test RAILS_ENV=production
- Run rake redmine:plugins NAME=redmine_contacts RAILS_ENV=production

The first two steps was successful, but last executing last command, following error would occur:
(in /home/.../redmine-2.2.3-0/apps/redmine/htdocs)

**Could not find sprockets-2.2.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.**

To see if the sprockets library is installed by executing command: #bundle show sprockets, it shows a newer version of this library is installed:
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think somehow the BitNami version of gem which is installed is not compatible with the sprockets-2.2.2 on the system and it requires 2.2.1. Maybe you should change to that version.

Try something like:

```
gem install sprockets -v 2.2.1
```